# Android Camera NoSuchMethodError on Exposure Lock

Tags: android, android-camera

I am getting a `NoSuchMethodError` on `Camera.Parameters.isAutoExposureLockSupported()`

How can this be avoided?

I am using:

```
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="17"
```

running application on HTC Wildfire S with Android 2.3.5

Comment: read the doc. this method is not available on your target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`isAutoExposureLockSupported()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#isAutoExposureLockSupported%28%29) was added in API level 14.

You will need `minSDKVersion` to be 14 if you want to use this. Your HTC Wildfire S with Android 2.3.5 has no idea about this method.

To fix, you can raise the minimum required SDK version in your manifest, or don't use it in lower versions by doing a version check at runtime.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
    // call isAutoExposureLockSupported() and do whatever you need
}
```